# rethinkdb web interface error looking for other database even a database name has been specified

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm trying to join two tables by parent id to child row name 'users_id' from the specific database via rethinkdb web interface, below is what I've tried

```
r.db('cn_chat').table('chat_que').eqJoin('users_id', r.table('connections'));
```

below is the error given by the web interface

[image]

where the expected database must be 'cn_chat' yet the web interface seems looking for the test database which did exist but not the correct database. Any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message gives a good hint: *"test.connection" doesn't exist.*
When you are using `r.table("connection")` by default it tries to connect to a db called "**test**", but your table is in the "**cn_chat**" i assume.

Try the following:

```
r.db('cn_chat').table('chat_que').eqJoin('users_id', r.db('cn_chat').table('connections'));
```